# The name for the class of theorems, propositions, lemmas

Tags: terminology, article-writing

Statements such as theorems, propositions, and lemmas are all (mostly) proven statements. They differ from, say, *definitions* by the fact that they describe consequences of axioms, rather than label a new object.

**Is there a name for the class of all "truthful statements" that describes each of the 'theorem' types?**

This class should consist of the following:

Theorem

Proposition

Lemma

Corollary

Claim

I don't think that *conjecture* or *hypothesis* belong in this class since they are results that have yet to be proved.

The term *statement* by itself seems too broad (taken from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic))):

> In logic, the term **statement** is variously understood to mean either:
>
>   (a)  a meaningful declarative sentence that is true or false, or
>
>   (b)  the
>   *assertion*
>   that is made by a true or false declarative sentence.

Similarly, *proposition* is already in the class, so it would perhaps be improper to call the class "propositions".

I have never heard of these things described as *facts*, though that feels like an appropriate name.

Comment: How about *results*?

Comment: What is the context you're thinking about? People do use 'Fact' in some contexts. Also, I think 'Proposition' can, in the right context, be used as the general term.

Comment: @Cronus The intended usage is just to refer to all 'facts' in various documents of mine. For example, something along the lines of "_in this paper, we use italic font in all_ [factual] _environments_" or "_all_ [facts] _in Section 3 use the methods of Melchior_".

Comment: I see... Yeah, *Facts* is definitely not ideal. Maybe "Proposition-like"?

Comment: George Gratzer, in *More Math Into LaTeX* (4th ed. 2007, section 6.4), uses the term *proclamation*, but this (a) includes definitions, and (b) would probably sound odd to anyone other than a LaTeX user (or possibly even a reader of Gratzer's book!). It seems like an artificial term associated with a particular typesetting system. Less artificially, how about *assertion*? If that is too broad, something like *numbered assertion*? ("Numbered" seems a little too specific, but I can't think of an unfussy alternative.)